# startActivityForResult does not send extras properly

Tags: java, android

I have a quiz game with 15 levels. After each level I present a popup with some info (game level, and some level rules). After level 15, a present final popup with info on how many points user has won. I use startActivityForResult to open the popups and send some extras and it works fine, until the last popup. After the last game, it should open the final popup with the overall score. But it doesn't do it properly. It opens on of my level popup, but with all the info filled with zeros. I don't know where it comes from. After I press OK, it opens final popup, but instead of overall score, I get 0. Here's the code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Popup_nivoi.class);
            nivo++;
            REQUEST++;
            switch(nivo) {
                case 2:
                {
                    brojPitanja = 11;
                    greska = 4;
                    mogucnostPreskakanjaPitanja = 3;
                    i.putExtra("brojPitanja", brojPitanja);
                    i.putExtra("vreme", 100);
                    i.putExtra("pravoNaGreske", greska);
                    i.putExtra("nivo", nivo);
                    i.putExtra("mogucnostPreskakanja", mogucnostPreskakanjaPitanja);
                    break;
                }
                case 3:
                {
                    brojPitanja = 12;
                    greska = 4;
                    mogucnostPreskakanjaPitanja = 2;
                    i.putExtra("brojPitanja", brojPitanja);
                    i.putExtra("vreme", 95);
                    i.putExtra("pravoNaGreske", greska);
                    i.putExtra("nivo", nivo);
                    i.putExtra("mogucnostPreskakanja", mogucnostPreskakanjaPitanja);
                    break;
                }
                case 4:
                {
                    brojPitanja = 13;
                    greska = 3;
                    mogucnostPreskakanjaPitanja = 2;
                    i.putExtra("brojPitanja", brojPitanja);
                    i.putExtra("vreme", 90);
                    i.putExtra("pravoNaGreske", greska);
                    i.putExtra("nivo", nivo);
                    i.putExtra("mogucnostPreskakanja", mogucnostPreskakanjaPitanja);
                    break;
                }
                case 5:
                {
                    brojPitanja = 14;
                    greska = 3;
                    mogucnostPreskakanjaPitanja = 2;
                    i.putExtra("brojPitanja", brojPitanja);
                    i.putExtra("vreme", 85);
                    i.putExtra("pravoNaGreske", greska);
                    i.putExtra("nivo", nivo);
                    i.putExtra("mogucnostPreskakanja", mogucnostPreskakanjaPitanja);
                    break;
                }
.
.
.
.
case 15:
            {
                brojPitanja = 24;
                greska = 0;
                mogucnostPreskakanjaPitanja = 0;
                i.putExtra("brojPitanja", brojPitanja);
                i.putExtra("vreme", 35);
                i.putExtra("pravoNaGreske", greska);
                i.putExtra("nivo", nivo);
                i.putExtra("mogucnostPreskakanja", mogucnostPreskakanjaPitanja);
                break;
            }
            case 16:
            {
                brojPitanja = 25;
                greska = 0;
                mogucnostPreskakanjaPitanja = 0;
                i.putExtra("brojPitanja", brojPitanja);
                i.putExtra("vreme", 30);
                i.putExtra("pravoNaGreske", greska);
                i.putExtra("nivo", nivo);
                i.putExtra("mogucnostPreskakanja", mogucnostPreskakanjaPitanja);
                break;
            }
            case 17:
            {
                Intent iFinale = new Intent(Kviz.this, Finale.class);
                iFinale.putExtra("UkupanSkor", brojacTacnihOdgovora);
                startActivityForResult(iFinale, 0);
                finish();
                break;
            }
        }
        cancelAllTimers();
        startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST);
    }
```

In my levels popup I do this to get extras:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras != null) {
            brojPitanja = getIntent().getIntExtra("brojPitanja", 0);
            pravoNaGreske = getIntent().getIntExtra("pravoNaGreske", 0);
            mogucnostPreskakanja = getIntent().getIntExtra("mogucnostPreskakanja", 0);
            vreme = getIntent().getIntExtra("vreme", 0);
            nivo = getIntent().getIntExtra("nivo", 0);
        }
```

And my whole finale popup class:

```
public class Finale  extends Activity implements OnClickListener{


      TextView cestitamo,ukupanSkor;
      Button ok;
      int brojOdgovora;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.finale);

        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null)
            brojOdgovora = getIntent().getIntExtra("brojTacnihOdgovora", 0);

        inicijalizujVarijable();
    }

    private void inicijalizujVarijable()
      {
        Typeface localTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "crazy_moj_3.ttf");
        cestitamo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCestitamo);
        cestitamo.setTypeface(localTypeface);
        ukupanSkor =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvUkupanSkor);
        ukupanSkor.setTypeface(localTypeface);
        ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOKCestitamo);

        ukupanSkor.setText("You answered correctly on " + brojOdgovora + " of 300 questions!");

        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
          public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
          {
            Intent localIntent = new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_OK, localIntent);
            finish();
          }
        });
      }


    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

The weird thing is that I have a popup for "time is up" and I use the same routine and the same code to send extras and to show how many points user scored and it works fine.

Comment: I assume this is the continuation from [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23270840/onactivityresult-not-working-properly), so I believe you have incorporated their answers, and the code that you posted here is the latest one. Also, it seems that you mis-copy-pasted the code for your popup `Intent` since I can't see the case for final stage (`case 16`, Finale?), so please add `case 15` and `case 16` first.

Comment: This is the latest code. I mis-copy-pasted, you noticed that well. I edited my post, now it's good.

Comment: So much repeated code! I suggest you learn about structured programming techniques such as methods and arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It opens one of my level popup, but with all the info filled with zeros.

This occurs because you put `startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST)` outside the `switch-case`. When `nova` is 17, the `Intent i` is not initialized with any extras, and it will always be called no matter what stage it is. Hence, the popup appears with all values being 0 (from the default value that you set).

> After I press OK, it opens final popup, but instead of overall score, I get 0.

This is because you use different name for your `extras`. When initializing the `Intent iFinale`, you use `UkupanSkor` for overall score. But inside the Finale activity, you use `brojTacnihOdgovora` instead.

---

My suggestion is to use same `Intent` to start the activity, and set the data based on the stage number. You only need to change `case 17`. Try:

```
case 17:
{
    REQUEST = 0; // set the request code to 0
    i = new Intent(Kviz.this, Finale.class); // set the intent to open final popup instead
    i.putExtra("brojTacnihOdgovora", brojacTacnihOdgovora); // set the extra name to match with the activity
    finish();
    break;
}
```